# Failed to transform iter().fold(....) into Rayon's par_iter().fold(....)

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use [Rayon](https://crates.io/crates/rayon) to initiate a series of top level threads to call a simulation function recursively.  The code works when using channel send & receive so it is multi-threading compatible, but it fails to compile with `par_iter()`.

```
fn simulate(initial_board: &Board, player: Player, level: u32, start: bool) -> Option<AMove> {
...

    #[inline(always)]
    fn evaluate_move(previous: Option<AMove>, new_move: &AMove, new_score: i32, player: Player) -> AMove {
    ...
    }

... 

let accumlator = |previous: Option<AMove>, a_move: &Option<AMove>| if let Some(AMove { board: ref a_board, .. }) = *a_move {
        ...
    } else {
        previous
    };

    if start && !winning {
        the_move = moves.par_iter().fold(the_move, accumlator);
    } else {
        the_move = moves.iter().fold(the_move, accumlator);
    }

    the_move
}
```

I get a compiler error on the line with par_iter() and I'm lost on how to fix these.

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::option::Option<AMove>: std::ops::Fn<()>` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:271:37    
    |
271 |         the_move = moves.par_iter().fold(the_move, accumlator);
    |                                     ^^^^ the trait `std::ops::Fn<()>` is not implemented for `std::option::Option<AMove>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::option::Option<AMove>: std::ops::FnOnce<()>` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:271:37
    |
271 |         the_move = moves.par_iter().fold(the_move, accumlator);
    |                                     ^^^^ the trait `std::ops::FnOnce<()>` is not implemented for `std::option::Option<AMove>`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/main.rs:271:20
    |
271 |         the_move = moves.par_iter().fold(the_move, accumlator);
    |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        expected enum `std::option::Option`, found struct `rayon::iter::Fold`
    |
    = note: expected type `std::option::Option<_>`
               found type `rayon::iter::Fold<rayon::slice::Iter<'_, std::option::Option<AMove>>, std::option::Option<_>, [closure@src/main.rs:224:22: 240:6 winning:_, level:_, player:_]>`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Otherwise, your question is likely to be closed as [*off-topic*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: My expectation is that par_iter() "behaves" the same as "iter()" or an advise to achieve similar behavior.

Comment: @SergeRobyns Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

Rayon's `fold` wants a function which produces an identity element, rather than a single base element. In your case, if `AMove` is `Copy + Send + Sync`, simply doing `moves.par_iter().fold(|| the_move, accumlator)` should be good enough.

If `AMove` is not `Copy`, use `|| the_move.clone()`.

Rayon may want to produce multiple identity elements to do different chunks in parallel and only merge the results at the end, that's why it needs be able to produce as many identity elements as it needs.

Check `fold`'s [signature](https://docs.rs/rayon/0.7.1/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelIterator.html#method.fold). Furthermore, if your accumulator returns the same type as the identity element, you probably want to use `reduce` instead (see linked docs for differences).

A different problem is that you can't use recursive closures the way you're trying to (Rust just can't do that). Use a named function for your accumulator instead.

Comment: It's getting better.
AMove has copy and clone for sure:
    #[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
    struct AMove {
        column: usize,
        board: Board,
        score: i32,
        cumulative_score: i32,
        cumulative_moves: i32,
    }

Nevertheless I tried to use your version of par_iter and I'm now getting a different kind of error.  The doc isn't helping much with my situation.  The error is hinting that I need to "fold" the results of fold, as much as the doc states the same, however the doc is using a sum function as an example and I  don't need it.

Comment: the_move = moves.par_iter().fold(|| the_move, accumlator);
expected enum `std::option::Option`, found struct `rayon::iter::Fold`

Comment: Did you try using reduce instead? Fold will give you another iterator of results, that you can then merge manually somehow (eg with reduce). If the accumulator is associative and returns AMove, then you should definitely use reduce rather than fold.

Comment: Based on all your inputs and an example in the Rayon demo, I'm now using par_iter(...).fold(| | ..).redeuce(| | ...) and it works.

Answer (score 0):

The solution lies in using `reduce` on the resulting `fold`.  Thanks for hinting me.  I finally found an example in the Rayon demo that paved the way to the solution for my case.  Here is the the way for future references.

```
moves.par_iter()
     .fold(|| None, accumlator)
     .reduce(|| None, |previous: Option<AMove>, a_move: Option<AMove>| {
        if let Some(a_move) = a_move {
            Some(select_move(&previous, &a_move, player))
        } else {
            previous
        }
    })
```

The most puzzling error was the initial one that came because I was using `fold(a,b)` instead of `fold(|| a,b)`, which complained about `Fn` and `FnOnce` and left me clueless.